# Redirection of a url using parameter

Tags: apache, redirect

I am trying to one URL with parameter to another url which doesn't have parameter.
I have written below things in apache conf file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/abc/others_jp$

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^utm_source=facebook_jp&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=2014_Facebook_contents&utm_term=other_facebook&utm_content=bridal$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.others.com/campaign/link-to-love-2015 [R=302,L]
```

When i tried, it shows like

http://www.others.com/campaign/link-to-love-2015?utm_source=facebook_jp&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=2014_Facebook_contents&utm_term=other_facebook&utm_content=bridal

Here I don't want to include the query string in redirected URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a `?` to the rewrite, that will truncate the query string:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.others.com/campaign/link-to-love-2015? [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Thanks... It works and now i am able to make correct redirection.